# Loop through JSON object in mysql function

Tags: mysql, json

I have a json object which has list of products under a bill. I want to write a mysql function for it which reads the data from the json and iterates over it one by one and inserts the same data to product and bill tables.

Here is my json object

```
{"billNo":16,"date":"2017-13-11 09:05:01","customerName":"Vikas","total":350.0,"fixedCharges":100,"taxAmount":25.78,"status":paid,"product":[{"productId":"MRR11","categoryId":72,"categoryName":"Parker Pen","cost":200,"quantity":2,"log":{"supplierId":"725","supplierName":"Rihant General Stores"}},{"productId":"MRR12","categoryId":56,"categoryName":"Drawing Books","cost":150,"quantity":3,"log":{"supplierId":"725","supplierName":"Rihant General Stores"}}]}
```

Here I have a mysql function which reads the data from the JSON

```
CREATE DEFINER=`mydb`@`%` FUNCTION `raiseOrder`(dataObject Json) 
RETURNS bigint(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE billNo BIGINT(11) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE customerName VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE date datetime DEFAULT NOW();
    DECLARE total Float(12,2);
    DECLARE taxamt Float(12,2);
    DECLARE fixedCharges Float(12,2);

    DECLARE products json;
    DECLARE productId bigint(15) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE categoryId bigint(11);
    DECLARE cost float;
    DECLARE categoryName varchar(64);
    DECLARE quantity int default 0;
    DECLARE supplierId bigint(11);
    DECLARE supplierName varchar(128);

    SET billNo = (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(dataObject, "$.billNo"));
    SET customerName = (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(dataObject, "$.customerName"));
    SET products = (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(dataObject, "$.products"));        
    SET productId = (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(products, "$[0].productId"));      
RETURN 1;
END
```

Now with these lines

```
SET products = (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(dataObject, "$.products"));        
SET productId = (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(products, "$[0].productId"));
```

I get the inner products json and the id of the 0th product. But I want a way to iterate over the array of the products.

Comment: I would honestly not do this in a MySQL function. I would write a script to do it, in Python or Ruby. Every other language besides MySQL stored routines supports more convenient ways of processing JSON.

Comment: But this I have to do in Mysql.

Comment: Currently MySQL has very limited functions for JSON processing, so it is recommended to use another language, however, a first approximation that can be implemented is something like [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7gDo2bNyaRZnmFiAsyQRnw/0), adjust the script as necessary.

Answer (score 31):

You can use a WHILE loop in conjunction with JSON_LENGTH to achieve this:

```
DECLARE json, products, product VARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT '{"billNo":16,"date":"2017-13-11 09:05:01","customerName":"Vikas","total":350.0,"fixedCharges":100,"taxAmount":25.78,"status":"paid","product":[{"productId":"MRR11","categoryId":72,"categoryName":"Parker Pen","cost":200,"quantity":2,"log":{"supplierId":"725","supplierName":"Rihant General Stores"}},{"productId":"MRR12","categoryId":56,"categoryName":"Drawing Books","cost":150,"quantity":3,"log":{"supplierId":"725","supplierName":"Rihant General Stores"}}]}
' INTO json;

SELECT json->"$.product" INTO products;

WHILE i < JSON_LENGTH(products) DO
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(products,CONCAT('$[',i,']')) INTO product;
    SELECT product;
    SELECT i + 1 INTO i;
END WHILE;
```

You'll probably need to do more than simply 'SELECT product' though ;-)

NOTE: MySQL JSON functions were added in 5.7.8 so you'll need to check your MySQL version first.

Answer (score 1):

Extension to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48214385/2227743), and if you want to loop through the keys of json object, you can do this via this way

```
declare _keys int default 0;
declare i int default 0;
declare _current_key varchar(50) default '';
select JSON_KEYS(product) into _keys;
while i < JSON_LENGTH(_keys) do
    select json_extract(json_unquote(_keys), concat('$[', i, ']')) into _current_key;
    set i = i + 1;
end while;
```